# Convert 02:45:00 to 2Hrs 45Min

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've a sheet in Excel, which have a calculated "Duration" field formatted to hh:mm:ss

What I am wondering is, is it possible to convert/output that value as a Text string also in another column, eg: 02:45:00 would output as 2Hrs 45Min

Have had a look around but can't see anything that helps. Maybe not possible?

Comment: Why did some one close to vote as off topic? Google spreadsheets is off topic but OP asks for both spreadsheets and Excel!

Comment: I believe this can be marked as "Closed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't state what you want to happen when there is no value - in your example, there are no seconds and you display nothing for seconds. Or, you just didn't mention it in your post, so I've provided solutions for both!

You need to concatenate and use text

```
=CONCATENATE(HOUR(A1),"HRS ",MINUTE(A1),"MINS ", SECOND(A1), "SECS")
```

[image]

And this will check if the Hour, Mins and Seconds exist and only show if they exist (quite a long formula sadly)

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(HOUR(A4) >0, CONCATENATE(HOUR(A4), "Hr "),""), IF(MINUTE(A4)>0, CONCATENATE( MINUTE(A4),"Min "),""), IF(SECOND(A4)>0,CONCATENATE(SECOND(A4), "Sec"),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is the best answer for me as it does exactly what I had envisioned. Apologies to every one else, for not being clearer in what I had hoped to be output. I did try all the other options which were all perfectly valid and did precisely what I had said, but the 2nd option (the "quite a long formula sadly") was perfect for my exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HOUR and MINUTE functions

```
=HOUR(A1)&"Hrs "&MINUTE(A1)&"Min"
```

Even if the A1 is text, it would parse.

Answer (score 0):

The pretty option would be to use the hour and minute functions in Excel, and then use the concatenate functions to combine those individual strings.

```
=CONCATENATE(HOUR(A8),"Hrs ", MINUTE(A8),"Min")
```

Would output `2Hrs 45Min`for the example you posted.

Less pretty is to parse the cell by characters (but you can use the MID function for all sorts of scenarios!)

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A1,1,2),"HRS ", MID(A1,4,2),"MIN")
```

It would output `02HRS 45MIN` for the cell you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the column to format like this, without conversions or calculations.

Use `[hh]"Hrs "mm"Min"` as the format, and it will display as you requested.